# REST API: Distance unit of measurement

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, api-design

The favourable unit of measurement for distance depends on culture.

For example, *feet* may be preferred over *metre*. This would render the following response model undesireable for some consumers of the API:

```
GET [uri]
{
    ...
    "distanceInMetres": 256
}
```

Perhaps the client should be able to provide their cultural preference:

```
GET [uri]?culture=en-US
{
    ...
    "distance": {
        "value": 840,
        "unit": "ft"
    }
}
```

Would this be an acceptable way to deal with this? I cannot seem to find any *best practices* or standards for this.

Comment: REST does not force you to use query parameters, but you can of course solve your problem this way. An other approach would be to use the `Accept-Language` HTTP header field and provide a value of `en-US` to get feet instead of meters. Though, I'm not sure if this is advisable in all circumstances. Imagine a user access your service with a browser that default language is set to en-US although the user lives in a country that acutally has a metric system - in that case query parameters would be preferable I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach seems perfectly correct - return a distance along with the unit. However, using query param seems not to be the idea.

For various language-specific features it's much better to use a header. There's even a header - `Accept-Language` but it will not be suitable here. Query params should be rather used to change the response data itself not the way that they're presented unless you use predefined query params to get the subset of fields e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 2 is certainly the way to go from JSON perspective. It's easily extendable, the request semantics don't need to be changed to support other regions/units.

Using HTTP parameter "to adjust" the object representation is perfectly ok as well.

Though not really compliant with classical REST principles but in some cases it quite practical to use path elements to provide such parameters.

```
GET [/app/en-US/<resource-id>]?params1=
```

This makes sense if your API requires some of the parameters to process majority of requests (for instance, to deliver region-specific values).